# Exception when converting tiff file to pdf file with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tiff

When I try to convert a `tiff` file to `pdf` file by using `itextpdf 5.5.5`, the following exception occurs:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Scanline must begin with EOL code word. at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TIFFFaxDecoder.readEOL(TIFFFaxDecoder.java:1303)
>   at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TIFFFaxDecoder.decode2D(TIFFFaxDecoder.java:811)
>   at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.getTiffImage(TiffImage.java:223)
>   at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.getTiffImage(TiffImage.java:315)
>   at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.getTiffImage(TiffImage.java:303)
>   at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:308) at
>   com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:242) at
>   com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:365) at
>   com.minstone.convert.PicConvertor.convertPicToPdf1(PicConvertor.java:81)
>   at
>   com.minstone.convert.DocConverter$ConvertWork.king2pdf(DocConverter.java:143)
>   at
>   com.minstone.convert.DocConverter$ConvertWork.run(DocConverter.java:99)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

I can open the `tiff` file in any image viewer, so it's valid.

Comment: Try using a getInstance() method with the boolean "recoverFromImageError". If that doesn't work, try instantiating a TiffImage object with the "direct" boolean set to true. If that doesn't work, please share the tiff.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I just using a getInstance() method with the boolean "recoverFromImageError" and fix it !

Comment: @MichaëlDemey You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 3):

iText has a few fallbacks when dealing with invalid or corrupt Tiff files. By default, these fallbacks aren't used, you'll need to explicitly use one of the getinstance() methods with the recoverFromImageError flag set to true  if you want iText to try and parse the invalid Tiff files (e.g. http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#getInstance%28byte[],%20boolean%29 )

If this boolean is set to true iText will only throw an error if it exhausted all of its options. This should be a sign to inspect your TIFF file...

Another workaround could be to use TiffImage and bypassing the Image class altogether. TiffImage also uses the recoverFromImageError flag, but it also has an additional flag called "direct" which might also solve your issues. (http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/codec/TiffImage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code snippet available, I guess you were using below code to read the image.

```
Image tiffImg=TiffImage.getTiffImage(randomAccessFileOrArrayObj, pageNum);
```

If so change it to (Add **true** to try recovering the file)

```
Image tiffImg=TiffImage.getTiffImage(randomAccessFileOrArrayObj, true, pageNum);
```